# Terminating a thread from within the thread in C/C++ without the thread handle

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I am writing a multithreaded application in windows using C. In my application I have to terminate the thread from within the thread. I am not having the handle to the thread, so I cannot use the close handle() function. Can anyone suggest an idea to handle the situation. Both MSDN c++ and WIN32 functions are accepted....Thanks, in advance :-)

Comment: Redesign your code so that you have the handle

Comment: Simply exit the thread procedure.

Comment: Why tagged ++? When you say it is C

Comment: Does exitthread() function terminates the thread....sorry I am new to programming..

Comment: Std:: thread + return, so much simpler

Comment: @JVApen - He says it is a C application

Comment: @viji - Why not read the manual page?

Comment: @ed: he said MSVC++ solutions would be ok

Comment: I guess he(?) needs to make up his mind C or C++

Comment: Please read (there is no safe way other than cleanly exiting your thread proc): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811

Comment: Redesign your code so that you don't need to explicitly terminate the thread.

Comment: what do you mean by "I am not having the handle to the thread"? [GetCurrentThread function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683182(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @AndriyTylychko GetCurrentThreadfunction returns a pseudohandle. This handle cannot be used to terminate the thread I guess.

Comment: @MartinJames no the thread has to run until the user terminates the thread(in my case)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to terminate the thread you can use [ExitThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682659(v=vs.85).aspx).

**Edit**: As Oliv mentioned in the comments `std::terminate` like `abort` and `exit` closes the entire program.

Comment: The poster says it is C

Comment: Does exitthreadex() function in C terminates a thread or I should call closehandle() even after calling the exitthread() function....

Comment: @viji ExitThread terminate the thread and you are done. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477550/closing-thread-using-exitthread-c)

Comment: @viji Look at the last link in the answer to check the ExitThread challenges.

Comment: Is it not necessary to call the closehandle() function.. If I am not using closehandle() whether it will be a safer/proper thread termination..

Comment: [std::terminate](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/exception.terminate#terminate.handler-2) terminates the entire program, not only the thread.

Comment: @Oliv Edited. Thanks for your note.